# Monitor or the Graphic card, something is faulty

Tags: graphics-card, display

I have this weird problem.

I got a brand new Samsung 22"monitor and hooked it up to my PC. It worked great.

After a few days I turned on the PC and the monitor wouldn't turn on. The LED keeps blinking. I checked the connnections, but it won't start. Then I hooked up the monitor to my laptop and **it worked**. So the problem must be in the PC, maybe  the video card. 
So i took the CPU to the repair guy and the monitor at his place WORKED, so the new monitor must be faulty, but it works for my laptop.

I cant think much on how to solve this.

Comment: How do you connect the monitor to your PC?

Comment: using an analog cable.

Comment: Why didn't you take both monitor AND the computer to the repair guy?

Comment: Had a similar one her. It worked when I changed the monitors **cable**.

Answer (score 1):

Is the resolution that your PC is set to supported by the monitor. Most will show a signal out of range message on the screen but its worth checking.
Also have you tried a known working monitor on your pc?
Have you checked the GPU is seated correctly?
You're not trying to run it off the onboard graphics when a GPU is plugged in are you? A simple question but I've seen it done.

Could probably do with a bit more detail to troubleshoot more effectively. So either update the question when you've tried these things or comment on my post.

Judging by the fact your monitor works fine with other machines you can probably rule out a faulty monitor.

Comment: I dont have any external Graphic card. im using the only on-board serial port.

Comment: ... serial port? that could be a problem... you need to use a VGA port

Comment: ahh sorry.. i meant VGA port.. not the serial port..

Comment: btw i was using he monitor few days back.. yesterday suddenly it stopped working. and even if the resolution isnt correct atlest the motherboard splash scrren shud be seen. right ?

Comment: Yes you should see the startup, as Alex has said did he do an exact test using the same connection you do? Check the cables, test another monitor on your system. Gradually rule things out using a process of elimination.

Comment: *> Is the resolution that your PC is set to supported by the monitor.*   My thoughts exactly. If the tech connected his own monitor to it and it worked, and you connected your monitor to your laptop and *that* worked, then the only feasible explanation is that your system is using a resolution that your monitor does not support (but the tech's monitor *does* support). You need to change the resolution. That said, the BIOS should be using a simple, VESA mode that *all* monitors are supposed to support, so try resetting the monitor in case it is a setting that has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

How did the techy test your graphics card, did he use the VGA, DVI-D or HDMI port? How are you connecting your screen, is it the same? When you tested it on your laptop did you use the same cable or did you disconnect it from the back of the monitor and use a spare? Check every conceivable combination of cables, using all your spares and hopefully you'll find a cable / connection combination that will work. Another thing to check, and I've done this before, is that you havn't accidentally plugged your monitor in to the on-board graphics card rather than your PCI-E graphics card.